# Array Error in Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm encountering "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" at the newEntry.x parts. I'm not sure why it would not read the objects within the for-loop, since in the console, it seems to recognize their values.

I'm writing a function that returns an expanded array with midpoints of the adjacent objects. It does that for certain number of iterations, hence the nested for-loop. I'm not sure what to do, as I've tried modifying the for-loop and splice, but came off unsuccessful.

```
function newList(iterations) {

  for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i += 1) {
    let concordiaLogo = [
      { x: 12.5, y: -100 },
      { x: 12.5, y: -112.5 },
      { x: 12.5, y: -125 },
      { x: 68.75, y: -68.75 },
      { x: 125, y: -12.5 },
      { x: 112.5, y: -12.5 },
      { x: 100, y: -12.5 },
      { x: 100, y: 0 },
      { x: 100, y: 12.5 },
      { x: 112.5, y: 12.5 },
      { x: 125, y: 12.5 },
      { x: 68.75, y: 68.75 },
      { x: 12.5, y: 125 },
      { x: 12.5, y: 112.5 },
      { x: 12.5, y: 100 },
      { x: 0, y: 100 },
      { x: -12.5, y: 100 },
      { x: -12.5, y: 112.5 },
      { x: -12.5, y: 125 },
      { x: -68.75, y: 68.75 },
      { x: -125, y: 12.5 },
      { x: -112.5, y: 12.5 },
      { x: -100, y: 12.5 },
      { x: -100, y: 0 },
      { x: -100, y: -12.5 },
      { x: -112.5, y: -12.5},
      { x: -125, y: -12.5 },
      { x: -68.75, y: -68.75 },
      { x: -12.5, y: -125 },
      { x: -12.5, y: -112.5 },
      { x: -12.5, y: -100 },
      { x: 0, y: -100 }
    ]
    for (let i = 0; i < (concordiaLogo.length-1) * 2; i += 2) {
      let newEntry = { x: 0, y: 0 };
      newEntry.x = (concordiaLogo[i].x + concordiaLogo[i+1].x)/2;
      newEntry.y = (concordiaLogo[i].y + concordiaLogo[i+1].y)/2;
      concordiaLogo.splice(i + 1, 0, newEntry);
    }
  }
  return concordiaLogo;
}
```

With an input of 3, I expected an array of 32*2**3, but it merely returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined."

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to iterate through an array longer than the one you have, so you're trying to set `x` on an array index that's undefined.

Here, iteration is trying to go through `(array.length - 1) * 2`, which is almost double your array length:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < (concordiaLogo.length-1) * 2; i += 2) {
      let newEntry = { x: 0, y: 0 };
      newEntry.x = (concordiaLogo[i].x + concordiaLogo[i+1].x)/2;
      newEntry.y = (concordiaLogo[i].y + concordiaLogo[i+1].y)/2;
      concordiaLogo.splice(i + 1, 0, newEntry);
    }
```

When you hit an index that's greater than the length of the array, `concordiaLoco[i]` is undefined, so you can't access `x` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You're going off the end of the array due to in incorrect bounds check: `i < (concordiaLogo.length-1) * 2`.  Let's call the array length "L1" When you get to the end of an array with an even number of elements, `i` will be `L1 - 2`.  Splicing in the midpoint will cause the array length to become 1 greater than the old length (`L1 + 1`).

Your test resolves to `i < (L1 + 1) - 1`, so `i < L1` - but we know `i` was `L1 - 2`, so the test will evaluate to true and the loop will continue by incrementing `i` by `2`.  `i` is now `L1`.  Unfortunately your code does: `concordiaLogo[i].x + concordiaLogo[i+1].x`.  `i + 1` evaluates to `L1 + 1`, one greater than the highest index in the array.  `concordiaLogo[i+1]` is undefined.

This solves the issue by checking the length of the array against an expected length (not sure how you got 32*2**3, the result increases the length of the array by the length of the array - 1):

```js
function newList(iterations) {

  let concordiaLogo = [
    { x: 12.5, y: -100 },
    { x: 12.5, y: -112.5 },
    { x: 12.5, y: -125 },
    { x: 68.75, y: -68.75 },
    { x: 125, y: -12.5 },
    { x: 112.5, y: -12.5 },
    { x: 100, y: -12.5 },
    { x: 100, y: 0 },
    { x: 100, y: 12.5 },
    { x: 112.5, y: 12.5 },
    { x: 125, y: 12.5 },
    { x: 68.75, y: 68.75 },
    { x: 12.5, y: 125 },
    { x: 12.5, y: 112.5 },
    { x: 12.5, y: 100 },
    { x: 0, y: 100 },
    { x: -12.5, y: 100 },
    { x: -12.5, y: 112.5 },
    { x: -12.5, y: 125 },
    { x: -68.75, y: 68.75 },
    { x: -125, y: 12.5 },
    { x: -112.5, y: 12.5 },
    { x: -100, y: 12.5 },
    { x: -100, y: 0 },
    { x: -100, y: -12.5 },
    { x: -112.5, y: -12.5},
    { x: -125, y: -12.5 },
    { x: -68.75, y: -68.75 },
    { x: -12.5, y: -125 },
    { x: -12.5, y: -112.5 },
    { x: -12.5, y: -100 },
    { x: 0, y: -100 }
  ]
  for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i += 1) {
    var expected = concordiaLogo.length * 2 - 1
    for (let i = 0; concordiaLogo.length < expected; i += 2) {
      let newEntry = { x: 0, y: 0 };
      newEntry.x = (concordiaLogo[i].x + concordiaLogo[i+1].x)/2;
      newEntry.y = (concordiaLogo[i].y + concordiaLogo[i+1].y)/2;
      concordiaLogo.splice(i + 1, 0, newEntry);
    }
  }
  return concordiaLogo;
}

function init() {
  console.log(newList(1))
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init)
```

Here is another way of doing the same thing, but without requiring an explicit length calc:

```js
function newList(iterations) {

  let concordiaLogo = [
    { x: 12.5, y: -100 },
    { x: 12.5, y: -112.5 },
    { x: 12.5, y: -125 },
    { x: 68.75, y: -68.75 },
    { x: 125, y: -12.5 },
    { x: 112.5, y: -12.5 },
    { x: 100, y: -12.5 },
    { x: 100, y: 0 },
    { x: 100, y: 12.5 },
    { x: 112.5, y: 12.5 },
    { x: 125, y: 12.5 },
    { x: 68.75, y: 68.75 },
    { x: 12.5, y: 125 },
    { x: 12.5, y: 112.5 },
    { x: 12.5, y: 100 },
    { x: 0, y: 100 },
    { x: -12.5, y: 100 },
    { x: -12.5, y: 112.5 },
    { x: -12.5, y: 125 },
    { x: -68.75, y: 68.75 },
    { x: -125, y: 12.5 },
    { x: -112.5, y: 12.5 },
    { x: -100, y: 12.5 },
    { x: -100, y: 0 },
    { x: -100, y: -12.5 },
    { x: -112.5, y: -12.5},
    { x: -125, y: -12.5 },
    { x: -68.75, y: -68.75 },
    { x: -12.5, y: -125 },
    { x: -12.5, y: -112.5 },
    { x: -12.5, y: -100 },
    { x: 0, y: -100 }
  ]
  while (iterations--) {
    concordiaLogo = concordiaLogo.reduce(function(acc, val, idx, source) {
      acc.push(val) // push the current element
      if (idx < (source.length - 1)) { // if there's no more elements, just push the current element 
        // add the midpoint of this and the next element
        acc.push({
          x: (source[idx].x + source[idx+1].x)/2,
          y: (source[idx].y + source[idx+1].y)/2
        })
      }
      return acc
    }, [])
  }
  return concordiaLogo;
}

    function init() {
      console.log(newList(3).length)
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init)
```